# Метод del не удаляет последний символ

Tags: python

```
values = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for count, value in enumerate(values):
    if value % 2 == 0:
        del values[count]
print(*values)
```

Test input:
1 1 1
Test output:
1

Пришлось делать с помощью генератора:

```
values = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(*[ values[i] for i in range(len(values)) if values[i] % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: Разве можно портить последовательность при итерации по ней?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122302/

Comment: print([value  for value in values if not value&1])

Comment: Явный дубликат, но не могу найти правильный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import cycle, compress

items = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

print(
    list(
        compress(
            items, 
            cycle((True, False,))
        )
    )
)
```

---

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

---

```py
items = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

print(
    list(
        compress(
            items, 
            cycle((True, False, False))
        )
    )
)
```

---

```
[1, 1, 1]
```